# Exclude weekends between a date range

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query and I am trying to select all records between a date range but I want to exclude weekends...anyone know if this can be done?

SQL isn't my strong point!

Below is the query;

```
SELECT
    tblTime.*,
    tblProjects.fldProjectDesc,
    tblProducts.fldProductID,
    tblProducts.fldProductDesc
FROM (tblTime
INNER JOIN tblProjects
    ON tblTime.fldProjectID = tblProjects.fldProjectID)
INNER JOIN tblProducts
    ON tblProjects.fldProduct = tblProducts.fldProductID
WHERE fldUserCode = 'pac'
AND fldDate BETWEEN CONVERT(varchar, '13/11/2015', 103) AND CONVERT(varchar, '15/11/2015', 103)
ORDER BY fldDate
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should be using convert(date ...) instead of convert varchar

Comment: @cybermonkey not a duplicate - I was not trying to calculate the number of days...I know questions should be kept to a minimum but at times it seems people are more concerned with pointing out faults rather than providing help

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister this was closer to what I was asking - I had seen the question but wasn't sure of how I could use any of the answers provided to it - thank you though

Comment: @PaulC It's a duplicate of the question provided by the user above you.

Comment: @cybermonkey Yes it could be seen as duplicate of that question but not the one you pointed to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`Dataname`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx) Function

```
SELECT tbltime.*, 
       tblprojects.fldprojectdesc, 
       tblproducts.fldproductid, 
       tblproducts.fldproductdesc 
FROM   (tbltime 
        INNER JOIN tblprojects 
                ON tbltime.fldprojectid = tblprojects.fldprojectid) 
       INNER JOIN tblproducts 
               ON tblprojects.fldproduct = tblproducts.fldproductid 
WHERE  fldusercode = 'pac' 
       AND flddate BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, '13/11/2015', 103) AND 
                           CONVERT(VARCHAR, '15/11/2015', 103) 
       AND Datename(weekday, flddate) NOT IN ( 'Saturday', 'Sunday' ) 
ORDER  BY flddate
```

Comment: Thank you - this worked. Although it has been pointed out in another question that there could be issues should the language change...this won't affect me however so your answer works for me